# How to boot Ubuntu from usb in Surface Go 3

Tags: ubuntu, operating-system, usb, surface, bootable

I want to dual boot ubuntu (preferably a light distro) in a surface go 3 with windows.

What I have tried:
I created the bootable drive with rufus, both in usb and sd.
I disabled secure boot.
I changed boot order in the UEFI.
I have restarted from recovery settings and selected usb boot.
I have also shut down and turned on with both [volume (-) + power] and [volume (+) + power]

What is happening:
Every time system loads windows xD. It is like the system doesn't recognize the OS loaded in the usb. Moreover I tried the usb on other pc and it loads Ubuntu just fine.

Currently I have only tried xubuntu 22.04 LTS.
The usb I'm using is normal with an adapter to USB type-c, possibly not OTG (at least when I plug it on my android phone, it reads its content without problems)

Any ideas? What should I try next?
Any help is welcome! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:
I was following this guide> https://itsfoss.com/create-live-usb-of-ubuntu-in-windows/

And there it said that "It would be a good idea to know if your system uses MBR or GPT (Rufus will create live USB accordingly)"

Well, following the instructions there, it happens that surface go uses GPT, so in rufus I selected that option as mentioned in the guide. It seems that i understood it wrong or it is bad explained, because the option to go is MBR. After creating the boot again with MBR, everything went smooth and i installed ubuntu succesfully.